# "He has a tendency of being aggressive" or "He is aggressive tendency"?

Tags: word-choice

I want to describe someone who has a tendency. Should I say

> He has a tendency of being aggressive.
>
> He is aggressive tendency.

Or are both wrong?

Comment: When in doubt, go for the simpler format - *"He tends to be aggressive"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> He has a tendency of being aggressive.

Edit: Gah. *of* is not used here, *to be* would be the more usual.

> *He is aggressive tendency.

Wrong (unless perhaps "he" is some sort of deity of anger).

> He has aggressive tendencies.
>
> He has an aggressive tendency.
>
> He has a tendency toward aggression.
>
> He tends toward aggression.
>
> He tends to be aggressive.

All fine, though the last two are perhaps a bit stilted and a bit weak, respectively.

Comment: I would thing *He has an aggressive tendency* would need *toward something* to complete it, as in, He has an aggressive tendency toward belligerence. Am I seeing this incorrectly? I see example 1 to be similar. Also, should one have tendencies of or to/toward? Thanks.

Comment: @Susan no, if someone has a tendency to be aggressive in a lot of situations, then "he has an aggressive tendency" would be fine. There is a slight difference between having "a tendency" and having "tendencies" in that the latter has a nuance of attempting to understand "his" psychology, though it's a rather airy-fairy pop-psychological phrasing to my mind (unless someone can actually discuss how one aggressive tendency someone has is meaningfully distinct from another).

Comment: I *don't* agree that the first example here ([a tendency of being aggressive](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+tendency+of+being+aggressive%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)) is "fine". There's only a single instance in Google Books, and it's clearly from an author with limited language skills (and apparently no copy editor either). By contrast, there are a claimed 1490 written instances of [a tendency toward aggression](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+tendency+toward+aggression%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), which I *do* think is "fine".

Comment: ...even more "fine" is [*a tendency **to be aggressive***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22a+tendency+toward+aggression%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22a+tendency+to+be+aggressive%22&tbm=bks), with a claimed 2770 hits.

Comment: @FumbleFingers conceded. The more jarring (to me at least) problem in the second example made me misread the first as "to be" even as I copy-pasted it! The mental auto-correct that is useful when reading but a death to sub-editing at play.

Comment: @Jon: I know what you mean. Per my comment to the Q, I see nothing wrong with your final (weak?) version, but that's no reason not to reverse my earlier downvote. On reflection though, I suspect OP probably shouldn't bother with the "medico-babble" implications of aggressive "tendencies" in the first place (learn to walk before you run, and all that). So my final recommendation would be ***He can be aggressive.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers agreed, and very much agreed on the last. The one exception is that the medico-babble form can be funny (guy goes nuts, punches someone in the face and throws a television out a hotel window; "He seems to have aggressive tendencies").

Answer (score 2):

*He has a tendency of being aggressive* sounds awkward and *He is aggressive tendency* is wrong. I would write *He has a tendency to be aggressive*.

Comment: Thanks, but I am still wondering, is the other way wrong or just not so good?

Comment: Thanks! So `He has a tendency to be aggressive.` should be the best in your opinion, right?

Answer (score 2):

> he has a tendency of being aggressive
> he (has an) aggressive tendency

in the second example, *aggressive* is being used as an adjective for tendency, meaning he has a very assertive tendency toward (something unnamed), so it can be eliminated.

[tendency](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tendency): an inclination *toward*; a direction or approach *toward* a place, object, effect, or limit; a proneness *to* a particular kind of thought or action. Therefore, when using *tendency*, follow it most often with to or toward.

> He has a tendency toward being aggressive.
> He has a tendency to be aggressive.

Other examples:

> The economy has shown a general *tendency toward* inflation.
>
> The Washington Times columnist Charles Hurt is out with a screed about President Obama’s horrible week and tried to blame him for the mess with Trayvon Martin, saying he has a *tendency toward* racial profiling.
>
> Obama On Romney: He Has "A *Tendency To* Shoot First And Aim Later"

Comment: I can't put my finger on exactly why, but I don't much like *"He has an aggressive tendency"*, though I have no such problem with the idiomatic standard *he has an aggressive **streak***. I also don't have so much of a problem when the *tendency* is more fully specified, as in *an aggressive tendency **to** [do something aggressive]*. All I can really say is superficially, *aggressive* seems syntactically similar to, say, *ill-tempered, hostile, calm, easy-going,* etc. But all of those sound awful to me as modifiers in *"He has an XXXX tendency"*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - agreed, and I also see Jon Hanna's point. I would be comfortable with *streak* because it has an implication of a character trait already demonstrated.

Answer (score 0):

The statement "he is an aggressive tendency" can be correct if used as as something which epitomizes "his" character.

I.E. "the main thing you need to know about The Hulk, is that he is an aggressive tendency as part of the Banner character"

With regards the other statement and it's critics: "he has a tendency to be aggressive" would be more usual - including an intransitive second verb.

The original "Of" would be a conceit or affectation. Or just plane ungrammatical.

Edited for clarity.